# Keep track of depth level of BFS in undirected graph

Tags: graph, breadth-first-search, depth

I found some answers on BFS and binary trees.
Any ideas what is the good way to do it in general undirected connected graph?
My final goal is determine whether a vertex is in the cycle of length less than 5,
so I want to do 5-deep BFS from that vertex in order to detect those cycles.

Comment: Please show what you did and where are you having difficulties.

Comment: @Michael Shevelin, I offer to solve your problem, using the algorithm **Depth first search**. If you need such method, reply on this message.

Comment: @VadimChernetsov I'll be happy to some advice.

Comment: @VadimChernetsov there in nothing wrong with using BFS. Infact BFS would be my first choice.

Comment: @c0der, thanks, used BFS for it.